# Action executes twice on submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My controller action is being executed twice.  Fiddler shows two requests and responses, and for the first one has an icon that indicates "Session was aborted by the client, Fiddler, or the Server."

But I can't figure out where this is happening, or why.

Here are the specifics:

I have a section of a view (ThingFinancials) that looks like this:

```
@{ using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmThing", "Thing", null, FormMethod.Get, new { id = "frmGo" }))
   {
       @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ThingID)
    <button id="btnGo">
        Thing is a Go - Notify People</button>
   }
}
```

The javascript for btnGo looks like this:

```
    $("#btnGo").click(function () {
        var form = $("#frmGo");
        form.submit();
    });
```

The action (stripped down) looks like this:

```
   public ActionResult ConfirmThing(int thingID)
   {
        [do some database stuff]
        [send some emails]

        var financials = GetFinancials(thingID);
        return View("ThingFinancials", financials);
   }
```

The only thing that looks unusual to me is that the URL you'd see would start out as `[Website]/Thing/ThingFinancials/47`, and after submission the URL would be `[Website]/Thing/ConfirmThing?ThingID=47`.

(If you're wondering why the Action name doesn't match the View name, it's because there are multiple form tags on ThingFinancials, and they can't all have the same action name.)

Is there a Server.Transfer happening behind the scenes, or something like that?

Comment: Shoudn't your FormMethod.Get be Post?

Comment: @BryanNaegele  I've tried it both ways.  The problem persists with both of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a submit button then you need to cancel the default behaviour when submitting with javascript, otherwise you will submit it twice. Try this:

```
 $("#btnGo").click(function () {
        var form = $("#frmGo");
        // event.preventDefault(); doesn't work in IE8 so do the following instead
        (event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
        form.submit();
    });
```

Comment: That was it!  I was using the <button/> tag, but I had thought that only <input type="submit"/> buttons could submit things on clicking.  Evidently a plain <button/> tag will do it, too.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have been of help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your `int thingID` is a query string parameter that stays with the request.  At the end of `ActionResult ConfirmThing(int thingID)`, all you're doing is returning a view.  If you'd rather see the clean URL ([Website]/Thing/ThingFinancials/47) you can make the following changes.

```
   public ActionResult ConfirmThing(int thingID)
   {
        [do some database stuff]
        [send some emails]

        // This logic is probably in the 'ThingFinancials' action
        // var financials = GetFinancials(thingID);

        // I'll assume we're in the same controller here
        return RedirectToAction("ThingFinancials", new { thingID });
   }
```

Comment: That is definitely a cleaner way to do it. But I still have the problem of ConfirmThing being executed twice, for no reason that I've been able to see.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your jquery event just add `stopImmediatePropagation()` to your jquery event.

```
 $("#btnGo").click(function (event){
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```